# Use width specifier in another specifier

Tags: c

I'm newbie in C.
My question is how could i use value (representing the width specifier) in specifier.

```
int width_specifier = 1;
char* star = "*";

for (width_specifier;width_specifier<10;width_specifier++)
{
  for (int j = 1;j<= width_specifier;j++)
  {
      printf("%width_specifier.s",star);//Problem is here
  }
  printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: What is the output you're trying to generate? Should the width come from `width_specifier` or `j`?

Comment: I was just trying to do that star exercise without 2 loop.Only 1 loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *width specifier* is used to control the minimum number of bytes to be written.  With `"%s"`, the output is padded with `' '`.

```
int main(void) {
  for (int width_specifier = 1; width_specifier < 10; width_specifier++) {
    printf("%*s\n", width_specifier, "*");
  }
}
```

Ouptut

```
*
 *
  *
   *
    *
     *
      *
       *
        *
```

---

To print various amount of  `*` per line [without an inner loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51109863/use-width-specifier-in-another-specifier?noredirect=1#comment89207670_51109863), code can pass a *precision* to limit the maximum number of bytes to be written with `".*s"`.

```
int main(void) {
  for (int width_specifier = 1; width_specifier < 10; width_specifier++) {
    int precision = width_specifier;
    printf("%.*s\n", precision, "**********");
  }
}
```

Output

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
```

Comment: can you explain why you reopened and why it is _not_ a duplicate? this format specifier thing is know for ages

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre True is was borderline.  Of the 2 interpretations of OP's goal answered here, I felt the dupe addressed the one and not the one OP was more likely interested in.

Answer (score 0):

If you read e.g. [this `printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) you will see that it is (kind of funny thinking about what you want to print)... The *star*.

That means an `int` argument will be read for the field width.

As in

```
printf("%*s\n", j, star);
```

Answer (score -1):

As in [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) you can always have the width itself a specifier:

```
printf("%*s", j, star);
```

Where that's taking `j` as the width argument, `star` as the value to be formatted.

Comment: Shouldn't `j` be `width_specifier`?

Comment: If it's trying to create a diagonal line, then no. If it's a vertical line then yes.

Answer (score -2):

```
printf("width_specifier = %c",star);
```

And other formatting: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm

Comment: The argument corresponding to `%c` must be a `char`, but `star` is `char*`.